# date problem in javascript

Tags: javascript

I've a problem with date in Javascript.
I need to increase by 1 day a date and I'm using this:

```
var myDate = new Date();
myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 1);
```

but when is the 30th of june the increased date will be the 31th of june and not the 1st of lst of july.

how can I obtain a correct increased data???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it won't. Try this snippet, works just fine.

```
var myDate = new Date();
myDate.setDate(30); // it's June as of the writing of this question
                    // so we're setting it to June 30th.
myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 1);
alert(myDate)
```

**Update:** I tried this in IE, Firefox, Chrome and Safari and it worked just fine.

Comment: you're right, I'm so stupid, my script were grabbing the wrong month value and he print me 31th of jly not june XD

Comment: Hope the rest of the day goes smoother.

Answer (score 1):

How about setting time of the myDate:

myDate.setTime(myDate.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)

Answer (score 0):

Date manipulation can be hard - use a library like [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) to do the hard work for you.